# How to use IdentityServer3 with ASP.NET Core Client?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver3

I have IdentityServer3 that we are using for authentication. Now I am developing a client application in ASP.NET Core 1.0. I Could not find any asp.net core client sample on official [IdentityServer repository](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients)

1>Is there any sample code available for IdentityServer3 with ASP.NET Core as client?
2>Does identity server 3 has its own nuget package for ASP.NET Core, something along the line of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

Look for `Creating an MVC client` section. The MVC client is developed using .NET Core. Its using IdentityServer4 for authentication but same would work with IdentityServer3

Comment: The above link "https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html" is not working any more..Do we have any working link?